# Do functional dependencies, if trivial, imply a subset relationship, given singleton domains?

Tags: sql, theory, functional-dependencies

Looking at definitions of FD. Where X and Y are subsets of a schema's attributes, I see both:

- FD X → Y is *trivial* if Y ⊆ X.
- FD X → Y is *trivial* if and only if Y ⊆ X.

Another characterization of "trivial" mentions “cannot possibly fail to hold” (C.J. Date). If *nontrivial* is explicitly characterized, then as "not trivial" (“of course”).

Now imagine some attribute *A* having a domain of just one value. Say, *A*'s type  includes just the value 1. Then, if any relation *R* includes *A*,  every set of attributes of *R* functionally determines *A*, i.e. X → A irrespective of whether {*A*} ⊆ X or not, because it cannot possibly not hold for any X ⊆ R. Reason:

> given any subtuple whatever, its *A*-component is given, too, being invariably 1.

So, is the subset condition characterizing FDs as being *trivial* both necessary and sufficient, in view of such domains?

(These singleton domains, in turn, could be called trivial, too, I guess, but still the definitions made me wonder. Or confused. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a relation R you can have one or more attributes constant. If A is such an attribute, than in that relation the following, *non-trivial*, dependency holds:

```
∅ → A
```

Thinking to the definition of functional dependency, this means that for *each* couple of tuples in an instance of R, they coincide always on A. This dependency is obviously non-trivial, since the right-hand part is not a subset of the left-hand part.

Moreover, as a consequence of this dependency, we have that X → A, for each subset X of attributes of R. This can be easily derived from the Armstrong’s axioms, by applying the reflexivity and transitivity rules:

```
X → ∅  (for the reflexivity rule, since for each X, ∅ ⊆ X)
X → A  (by applying the transitivity rule to X → ∅ and ∅ → A)
```

Comment: So, I gather, for the biconditional about the subset relationship to be true, it needs to be understood that the type of A is arbitrary? This additional premise, sort of, supplying  "in general".

Comment: @B98: yes, exactly. Actually, in different instances of the same relation, you can have *different* values for A, so A can have any domain. The dependency “says” only that, inside *any* instance, the attribute A has always the *same* value.